# Broser pre-filling input fields but after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed my own code for float labels on input. Works smoothly but not when browser prefilling input on page load.

```
function checkInputsValue() {
  $('.input-box').each(function() {
    $input = $(this).find('input');
    if ($input.val() == '') {
      moveLabelDown($input);
    }
    else {
      moveLabelUp($input);
    }
  });
}
```

I fire this jquery on document ready. Problem is it finds the input value as empty on page load, even though it isn't when the page is fully loaded.
It's like the browser fills the input only after the jquery ready event. Even setting a timeout on the function doesn't solve the problem cause it looks like the check is done before the timeout delay.

**EDIT WITH SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function moveLabelUp(input) {
    $input = input;
    $input.parent().addClass('filled');
  }

  function moveLabelDown(input) {
    $input = input;
    $input.parent().removeClass('filled');
  }

  function checkInputsValue() {
    $('.input-box').each(function() {
      $input = $(this).find('input');
      if ($input.val() == '') {
        moveLabelDown($input);
      }
      else {
        moveLabelUp($input);
      }
    });
  }

  checkInputsValue();

  $('input, textarea').focus(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    moveLabelUp($this);
  });

  $('input, textarea').blur(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($input.val() == '') {
      moveLabelDown($this);
    }
  });

  $('select').parent('.input-box').append('<div class="select-arrow"></div>');

});
```

```css
.input-box {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  &.filled {
    label {
      font-size: 1.2rem !important;
      top: 6px !important;
      transform: none !important;
    }
  }
  input, textarea, select {
    background-color: $primary;
    color: $tertiary !important;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    width: 100%;
    // Cover chrome autocomplete styles application
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px $primary inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: $tertiary;
  }
  input, select {
    @extend .rounded-max;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 18px 25px 0 25px;
    & + label {
    top: 50%;
    left: 25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
  }
  textarea {

  }
  select {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    & + label {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    & ~ .select-arrow {
      width: 16px;
      height: 8px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 20px;
      pointer-events: none;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background: image-url('icons/arrow-down.svg') no-repeat center/contain;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
  }
  label {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: $tertiary;
    transition: font-size 0.2s, top 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
    cursor: text;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box filled my-4">
  <%= form.text_field :username %>
  <%= form.label :username %>
</div>

<div class="input-box filled my-4">
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
  <%= form.label :password %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the runnable code by using code snippet

Comment: Updated, there it is. It is actually from a rails application.